# VBA Run-time error 13: Type mismatch when calling function with HTMLDocument as argument

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, mshtml, vba

The code below works fine on one machine and returns an error on the second when calling the function with two parameters (when calling with one parameter, it works fine). The function is in another module. Can anybody give me an advise what can be wrong with it?

Both machines runs Excel 2016 and IE11.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
With ie
    .Silent = True
    .navigate serverURL 'URL as string
    .Visible = False
End With

Set htmlDoc = ie.document

Call WaitForLoad(ie) 'this works fine

For Each htmlElement In htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
   If htmlElement.Type = "submit" Then htmlElement.Click: Exit For
Next

Call WaitForLoad(ie, htmlDoc) 'this returns Run-time error 13: Type mismatch
```

Functions:

```
Public Function WaitForLoad(browser As InternetExplorer, _
                        Optional ByVal doc1 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, _
                        Optional ByVal doc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument) _
                        As Variant

If Not browser Is Nothing Then
    Call LoadTimeoutSettings
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until (browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE) Or (Now > StopTime)
End If

If Not doc1 Is Nothing Then
    Call LoadTimeoutSettings
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until (doc1.readyState = "complete") Or (Now > StopTime)
End If

If Not doc2 Is Nothing Then
    Call LoadTimeoutSettings
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until (doc2.readyState = "complete") Or (Now > StopTime)
End If
End function


Function LoadTimeoutSettings()
StartTime = Now
StopTime = StartTime + TimeValue(TimeOut) 'TimeOut="00:00:15"
End Function
```